# What's the exact definition for strong correlation in condensed matter physics?

Tags: condensed-matter, fermi-liquids, strong-correlated

Can we judge or define the strong correlation (for electron system) in condensed matter physics just by the competition of kinetic energy and interaction energy term in the total Hamiltonian? I mean by some brief estimations one can finally get the following relation:
$$\dfrac{I.E.}{K.E.} \propto \dfrac{r_s}{a_0} $$

where $r_s$ the average distance between electrons and $a_0$ is Bohr radius.So if you take the limits:

1. $r_s \gg a_0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad I.E. \gg K.E. \quad \Rightarrow $ Strong correlation system;
2. $r_s \ll a_0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad I.E. \ll K.E. \quad \Rightarrow $ Weak correlation system.

If this understanding is wrong,then what's the exact definition for strong correlation in condensed matter physics,especially in electron system? Not just a general description such as beyond Fermi liquid theory or Hubbard model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no precise definition of strong correlation in condensed matter. A working definition is beyond Fermi liquid or mean-field theory. Typically this happens when the interaction is strong.

Comment: @ Everett You:  Personal Understanding: The electron has two kinds of degrees of freedom (ignore any other possible DOFs). One is the charge (Coulomb interaction) and the other one is spin (Pauli exclusion principle). So the definition should contain both these ingredients?